# Propensity Score in R from Stata Code

Tags: r, stata

I'm trying to replicate the pscore command from Stata in R.  There seem to be quite a few R packages for dealing with propensity score matching, but I can't figure out how to get the desired output.

Stata Code :

```
pscore dmmfd sexhead agehead educhead lnland vaccess pcirr rice wheat milk oil egg [pw=weight], 
       pscore(ps98) blockid(blockf1) comsup level(0.001);

****Nearest Neighbor Matching;
attnd lexptot dmmfd [pweight=weight], pscore(ps98) comsup;

****Stratification Matching;
atts lexptot dmmfd, pscore(ps98) blockid(blockf1) comsup;

****Radius Matching;
attr lexptot dmmfd, pscore(ps98) radius(0.001) comsup;

****Kernel Matching;
attk lexptot dmmfd, pscore(ps98) comsup bootstrap reps(50);
```

Current R Code :

```
pscore(formula = dmmfd ~ sexhead + agehead + educhead + lnland + 
vaccess + pcirr + rice + wheat + milk + oil + egg, data = hh_98.df)
```

The pscore function in R doesn't appear to have the ability to set blockid, comsup or level so I'm not sure what to do about this as the desired numbers are not correct.

The different types of matching seem to be parameters set, but I'm not sure which package to use for these.  I think the MatchIt() package may be best for this, but I can't get the coefficients output.

Data : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ow510wzv6ohxa96/hh_98.df.csv?dl=0

Screenshot of desired output :

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is the question being asked here.

Comment: @Metrics my question is how would I recode the Stata code into R?  I was able to do a simple propensity score matching, but am not sure what package to use in order to do blockid, comp and levels

Comment: There are already so many packages in [R](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~estuart/propensityscoresoftware.html). You should check those first.